# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find a class "com.life.Life"

Tags: java, android

I was tring to load a class from a **jar file** through `DexClassLoader`:

```
public class AndroidClassLoader implements ClassLoader {

    private Class class1;

    @Override
    public Class execute(File file, String packge) {
         class1 = null;
         try{
             DexClassLoader loader = new DexClassLoader(file.toURI().toURL().toString(), FXActivity.getInstance().getDir("outdex", 0).getAbsolutePath(), null, FXActivity.getInstance().getClassLoader());
             class1 = loader.loadClass(packge);
         }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return class1;
     }
}
```

After running the above code, an error will be thrown:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find a class "com.life.Life"
 of Path: DexPathList [[zip file "/storage/emulated/0/Life.jar"],
 nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

The name of the jar file was **Life.jar** and here's its content:

```
package com.life;

public class Life
{
   public String getMessage()
   {
     return "Life is Beautiful!";
   }
}
```

**Any idea on how to fix this?**

Comment: Are u taking .jar files from file manager or from libs?

Comment: I got a jar file located at /storage/emulated/0/Life.jar and I want to load it at runtime.

Comment: @M Kosztolowicz, can you help me with this one.

Comment: @Jens, can you help me with this one.

Comment: @darkravedev, do you have any idea about this one?

Answer (score 0):

Your package value should be "com.life.Life"

ie., class1 = loader.loadClass("com.life.Life"); 
can you try this and let me know its that working for you

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't worked, the same error.  :)