# java.io.IOException: Zip archive '/storage/emulated/0/Life.jar'

Tags: java, android

In connection to this unresolved problem: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find a class “com.life.Life”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848344/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-a-class-com-life-life), I decided to **print** all the **classes** in the **Life.jar**:

```
DexFile dx = DexFile.loadDex(file.getAbsolutePath(), File.createTempFile("opt", "dex",FXActivity.getInstance().getCacheDir()).getPath(), 0);
// Print all classes in the DexFile
for(Enumeration<String> classNames = dx.entries(); classNames.hasMoreElements();) {
    String className = classNames.nextElement();
    Log.e("CLASS", className);
}
```

But it throws an **error** saying:

```
java.io.IOException: Zip archive '/storage/emulated/0/Life.jar'
doesn't contain classes.dex (error msg: Entry not found)
```

**How to resolve this?**

Here's the content of **Life.jar**:

```
package com.life;

public class Life
{
    public String getMessage()
    {
       return "Life is Beautiful!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the jar is in proper format and contains dex files

Comment: Content is ok. Extract the jar and check whether it contains classes.dex or not. Because your code will try to print all the classes inside classes.dex. ie) it expects classes.dex

Comment: It doesnt have any .dex files since its just a standard jar file.

Comment: Since it is a standard jar file it won't. Because dex is for android not for ordinary jars. Then Build an apk with the with Life.class. Then you will get classess.dex files..

Comment: @Shriram, can you check the first problem, do you have any idea about it?